# Post Request nonworking in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, cross-browser, forms, http-post

```
alert();  // this alert appears for Firefox too.
$('<form action="Order/Create" id="Formabc" method="POST">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="WeightUnit" value="' + Units + '">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="Premium" value="' + 'N/A' + '">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="Cost" value="' + Cost + '">' +
            '</form>').submit();
```

I am posting this form on jQuery Modal Model submit.

It is working in Chrome, Safari and IE, but not in Firefox..

Comment: Why don't you use `$.ajax`?

Comment: Need to call for a full post back...
Why it don't work.. any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to invoke `appendTo("body")` before `submit()`?

Comment: Are you sure that `Units` and `Cost` are defined? Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7117103/2286990)?

Comment: "It is working in Chrome, Firefox and IE. not in Firefox.."??

Comment: Are you sure that Units and Cost are defined? Yes 
 Have you seen this answer? added append...

Comment: http://localhost:49794/Order?WeightUnit=10&Premium=5&Cost=10.00#

Adding to the body.. Makes form post but to a wrong action

http://localhost:49794/Order

instead of http://localhost:49794/Order/Create

Answer (score 1):

As MasterAM suggested, using ajax would be a better shout, but if you can't for what ever reason, append that form to the DOM and fire it then.

```
$('body').append('<form action="Order/Create" id="Formabc" method="POST">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="WeightUnit" value="' + Units + '">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="Premium" value="' + 'N/A' + '">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="Cost" value="' + Cost + '">' +
            '</form>');


$('#Formabc').trigger('submit');
```

But ajax is still a better way to go.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/