# Cross Browser Issue with form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please I have a issue with the script below, am using it to submit a for, it works well on chrome but it doesn't work on firfox, please what could be the problem.

```
        <script>
        var transac_code = <?php echo json_encode($transac_code); ?>;
        var amount = <?php echo json_encode($amount); ?>;
        //window.location.href = "web_pay.php?transac_code=" + transac_code + "&amount=" +amount;

        $('<form action="web_pay.php" method="POST">' + 
        '<input type="hidden" name="transac_code" id="transac_code" value="' + transac_code + '">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="'+ amount +'" />' +
        '</form>').submit();

    </script>
```

thanks for your assistance

Comment: Take a look at this one, maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117084/jquery-form-submit-on-chrome-works-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: This is a _guess_, but maybe Firefox doesn't like that you post a form that doesn't exist in the DOM?

Comment: Lordie; use ajax for this. Why are you embedding a form inside JS like that?

Comment: that looks extremely code-smelly.. you should try using regular AJAX-calls instead, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the form the document.

```
$("...").appendTo(document.body).submit();
```