# jquery .html not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

So i have a page where i have a quote request form for a client.

the doc type is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

What i am doing is, generating the forms submit button via jquery, so if the client browser has js disabled, the submit button does not appear.

the HTML is as follows.

```
    <div id="buttonscript">


    </div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#buttonscript").html('<input type=\"image\" name=\"Submit\" src=\"<?=$img_dir?>/button-submit_off.png\" alt=\"Submit\" class=\"nostyle\" style=\"margin-left:-4px;\" />');
});
</script>
```

It works fine in all browsers but FF it seems.

I have another `$(document).ready(function() {` on the page would this cause conflicts?

the second one is to invoke jquery.validate plugin on the form.

**UPDATE**

tried removing all escapes before ". didnt work. No errors in console as far as i can tell. works fine EVERYWHERE but FF.

**UPDATE**
**I AM A NOOB**

Lol anyways, i realized there had to be something funky going on , considering i know that the errors coming up were stating that jquery was undefined....then i remembered an .htaccess directive allowing scripts to only run from same domain, and i had previously been hosting my jquery library, but decided to let google do that for me.... in other words, there wasnt crap wrong with any of my code...it was server configuration.. FINALLY figured it out!

Comment: Does the validate need to be in its own `$(document).ready()`? That could be the problem... Also, do you need to escape your double quotes since you start `.html()` with a single quote?

Comment: also have tried `.append` to no avail

Comment: I would suggest taking out the `$(document).ready()` for the validate and test whether it works or not then.

Comment: ive always escaped double quotes...but i can try that. and if the split `$(document).ready()` was the problem youd htink it would conflict in all other browsers as well

Comment: You don't need to escape `"` inside single quotes.

Comment: taking out the other `$(document).ready` didnt do a thing

Comment: Do you get a js error in the console?

Comment: Works for me in FF 12. http://jsfiddle.net/TqyLv/

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319235/jquery-form-submitting-in-firefox

Comment: ive removed the escapes on the quotes, nothing.

Comment: think it could have something to do with the php tag in the html?

Comment: strange that jsfiddle does work and mine doesnt. i also tried removing the php dir reference and still nothing

Comment: no error in the console either

Comment: @RezenX What version of FF are you in?

Comment: try: 

`$('#buttonscript').html('<span class="something">yo!</span>')` 

can you insert anything in ff at all?

Comment: Are you sure that your code doesn't work? I'm running this on jsfiddle and it's working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/FireDragonDoL/xrUym/

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why you adding slashes to the double quotas while you started with single ones

```
'<input type=\"
```

try to remove the slashes

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` ?

Try wrapping your code like this in case there is a conflict:

```
(function($){
    // safely use $ as an alias for jQuery in here
}(jQuery));
```

If you look at the DOM in the console, is anything being inserted? In other words, is the problem that nothing is inserted or is it that what's being inserted in incorrect?

In any case, I think there is a better solution for what you're trying to do: On your `html` tag add a `no-js` class:

```
<html class="no-js">
```

and then remove the class via jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('html').removeClass('no-js').addClass('js');
});
```

Then you can hardcode the `input` but have it be hidden when there is not JavaScript. In CSS 
, you could put something like:

```
.no-js #buttonscript{ display:none; }
```

Then you don't have to worry about inserting it at all.

Answer (score 0):

it all came down to server configuration. realized that jquery library was now being hosted externally. and i had an .htaccess directive blocking external scripts. silly me, i forgot i had done that ages ago!

Comment: yeah what throws me off though...is why was chrome and IE still displaying everything just fine haha. who knows!